# How do I persist/apply sort descriptions to a .Net C# ListViewCollection?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a ListViewCollection defined in my application.
The ListViewCollection is displayed in a DataGrid in a WPF desktop application.
I'd like to save and reapply the sort descriptions.

**Here is a code snippet:**

```
var sortDescriptions = ItemsView.SortDescriptions;

// Do some stuff
ItemsView = new ListCollectionView(Items)

// Reapply the previous column sorts
ItemsView.SortDescriptions.AddRange(sortDescriptions);
ItemsView.Refresh();
```

The above code does not seem to work.
What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks, John

Comment: What are items? You probably need to get the default view of whatever it is at least.

Comment: Save to where and re-apply from where...?